# Zero in-front of a number getting deleted

Tags: python, string, binary

The below program snippet is running fine with any inputs except those starting with 0

```
NK = list(map(int,input().split()))
string = input()
print(string)
n = int(string)
A = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
print(A)

N = NK[0]
K = NK[1]

for i in range(K):
    temp = A[0]
    for j in range(0,len(A)-1):
        A[j] = A[j+1]
    A[N-1] = temp
print(A)
```

For input

```
5 3
01111
```

Im getting error since while converting the string to int the leading 0 is getting deleted.
Is there any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: Can you tell what does your program do, your expected output

Comment: Why are you converting your input to `int`, then back to `str`? You've got `n = int(string)`, then the only place you use `n`, you immediately do `str(n)`.

Comment: It performs a cyclic shift to the left K no. of times @Sujay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove below line:

> n = int(string)

and change this line :

> A = [int(x) for x in str(n)]

to this :

> A = [int(x) for x in string]

Comment: Could you clear my doubt that why is it that converting the whole string to integer the leading zeroes are ignored?-@Hami

Comment: dear @RishavMitra

leading zeros in integers mean nothing. if you put zero before a number as many as you want, there is no effect on value of the number. e.q : 10 = 0000000000010